# UIWebView Javascript to select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

I am running JavaScript on `UIWebView` but unfortunately it not working.

I when user touch on webpage I would like to get text for touched element and also highlight that element.

//tried this

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.onclick  = function (e) {e.target.style.background='#ff3355';          };"];
```

// tried this

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick  = function (e) {e.target.style.background='#ff3355';          };"];
```

Hopever it is working when I check on web browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/D9NC3/62/

Can someone please suggest what is correct way to use that?

Comment: Does anyone know answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer!!

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.ontouchstart  = function (e) {e.target.style.background='#ff3355';};"];